# Javascript+Jquery. Как получить определенное значение из результата api запроса?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю API get запрос. 
Получаю данные в там виде:

```
{
    "joined": {
        "@user1:server": {
            "avatar_url": null,
            "display_name": "John Doe"
        },
        "@user2:server": {
            "avatar_url": null,
            "display_name": "Jane Doe"
        }
    }
}
```

Всё это получаю в переменную data.
Можно ли как то быстро получить из этого display_name от @user2:server?

Спасибо!

Comment: `console.log(data.joined["@user2:server"].display_name);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = {
    "joined": {
        "@user1:server": {
            "avatar_url": null,
            "display_name": "John Doe"
        },
        "@user2:server": {
            "avatar_url": null,
            "display_name": "Jane Doe"
        }
    }
}
console.log(Object.values(data.joined)[1].display_name);
```

Comment: Спасибо! А можно указать не в лоб user2,а допустим "не равно user1"?

Comment: Обновил код, будет брать 2 объект из Json'а.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз огромное!